# UIButton stretches in iPhone6 simulator while using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout, xib

I am a newbie in designing UI using autolayout. For this i used the XIB using 3.5inch window. Everything works fine till iPhone5s simulator but the frame stretches when i run it in iPhone6 and iPhone6plus. Please help me...

[image: iPhone 6 simulator]

[image: iPhone 5s simulatore]

[image: Constraints used]

Comment: which constraints did you set?

Comment: for green button i have set leading constraint

Comment: Check wether there's some active option for your buttons named Adjust to Fit.

Comment: Set the width = some value; rather going with <=. It says width <= 115 constraints, so try deleting that.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following Constraints:

**GREEN VIEW**

a. leading space to superview
b. Top space to superview
c. fixed height
d. select both view and give equal widths constraints

**RED VIEW**

a. trailing space to superview
b. Top space to superview
c. fixed height

Comment: Thank you.... It worked... One more help ..  How to fix watch label issue?? See they are different in both screen..

Comment: Select Watch, Camera and Upload Views(Buttons) Go to Editor > Pin > widths Equally. You can do the same to Red view and Green View. Views width will increase according to the screen size.

Comment: fixed the height with of image and give it top space and leading space constraints..don't add horizontal spacing between the image .Due to which it is expanding.